# php How to get it pure array from Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

Here is my Query

`$reminderData = Reminder::where('status', 1)->get()->toArray();`

Here is my Result

```
[
{"id":1,"reminder_type":2,"reminder_name":"first","reminder_date":"2016-10-26"},
{"id":2,"reminder_type":2,"reminder_name":"second","reminder_date":"2016-10-26"},
{"id":3,"reminder_type":2,"reminder_name":"third","reminder_date":"2016-10-26"},
]
```

But i need like

```
[
["id":1,"reminder_type":2,"reminder_name":"first","reminder_date":"2016-10-26"],
["id":2,"reminder_type":2,"reminder_name":"second","reminder_date":"2016-10-26"],
["id":3,"reminder_type":2,"reminder_name":"third","reminder_date":"2016-10-26"],
]
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: You're showing JSON there, not an array. Where are you converting to JSON? And the desired output is not valid JSON.

Comment: @jszobody that's returned by eloquent query .. i just need to show up in the output

Comment: No, it's not. Your "result" is a json string, that's not what Eloquent `toArray()` provides.

Comment: Do this: `dd(Reminder::where('status', 1)->get()->toArray());`.

Comment: It's the same result when i try toArray() or toJson()

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Somewhere you are outputting the array as JSON and you are confused. If you try that `dd` code I gave you, you'll see you absolutely have an array from Eloquent, not json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, convert JSON array to Array and only get one object from the Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597454/laravel-convert-json-array-to-array-and-only-get-one-object-from-the-array)

Comment: @jszobody It returns, but its structure like `array:3 [
  0 => array:10 [....`

Comment: Excellent. So: you see you have an array of arrays. Which is exactly what you wanted. Your code is fine, it's already giving you the structure you are asking for.

Comment: yeah, but will the `dd()` stop my next queries. ie., i am constructing this and returning $result `$Response = array('draw' => Input::get('draw'), 'data' => $reminderData);` . It simply returns the $reminderData in array format and not the other ones..

Comment: The `dd` is just proving you to that you have an array of arrays already. _The code you show here in your question works perfectly._ If you are getting JSON later on, when outputting the data, then you need to update your question and show _THAT_ code. No one can help you if you don't show the code that has the problem.

Comment: @jszobody I understood your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually returns array of arrays. You you'll use `dd()` on both levels, you'll see an `array` data type.

Also, you can get only columns you need with `->get(['id', 'reminder_type', 'reminder_date'])`

Comment: ah, i am getting this as my result now `{"2":1,"1":2,"3":3}`

Comment: @SA__, oh yeah, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Ohh.. that's ok .. Stilll i am getting like this `[{"id":1,"reminder_type":2,"reminder_date":"2016-10-26"},{"id":2,"reminder_type":1,"reminder_date":"2016-10-26"},{"id":3,"reminder_type":3,"reminder_date":"0000-00-00"}]`

Comment: ah, i tried in your way.. not sure, why it is not giving the expected behaviour. btw i am using laravel 5.1

Comment: @SA__ try to do `dd($reminderData )` and you'll see an `array` data type. Then try to do `dd($reminderData[0])` and it will show you a type of one row which will be also `array`.

Comment: It's showing like `array:10 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "reminder_type" => 2
  "reminder_name" => "first"
  "reminder_date" => "2016-10-26"
]` like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126733/discussion-between-alexey-mezenin-and-sa).

Comment: @SA__ that's correct. You can see `array:10` in your result.

Answer (score 0):

As wrote in comments:

> it looks like dirty hack and it can cause unexpected behavior with more complicated data

---

You can return

```
 json_decode(Reminder::where('status', 1)->get(), true);
```

as already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597454/laravel-convert-json-array-to-array-and-only-get-one-object-from-the-array)

Comment: why on Earth you want to `json_decode` an Eloquent collection?

Comment: Never, but the question is to return an array of array, and it does.

Comment: The default array structure returned by Laravel is similar to json formatted arrays, so in order to let PHP convert it to standard array, you must use json_decode method

Comment: @DoaaMagdy, it doesn't look like json at all. If you see `{}`, it doesn't mean it's json. It's completely different data type. The code above will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reminderData = Reminder::where('status', 1)->pluck('column_name1', 'column_name2')
```

In the laravel 5.0 and above version "pluck" method return data in the array format

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$values=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select("select * from  your_table");
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
var_dump($values);
```