# How to Convert string response to array laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to change this response to array
This is value what i received via API: `"{'db_password': 'TgD31F#4124!'}"`
I would like to remove the quotes and only keep `TgD31F#4124!`

Code Example

```
$db = Http::get(HERE_URL);
return $db->body(); // received it here "{'db_password': 'TgD31F#4124!'}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel, convert JSON array to Array and only get one object from the Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597454/laravel-convert-json-array-to-array-and-only-get-one-object-from-the-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `json()` method or `object()` method on your response variable. [API Reference](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Response.html#method_json)

```
json method: Get the JSON decoded body of the response as an array or scalar value.
```

```
object method: Get the JSON decoded body of the response as an array or scalar value.
```

Usage:

```
$response = Http::get("www.api.com/...");
$decodedBody = $response->json();
```

OR

```
$decodedBody = $response->object();
```

EDIT:
All available methods are listed in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client).

Comment: sorry , but still same error

Comment: Have you tried to use `$decodedBody['db_password']` in order to access your desired field value? It seems like you're doing something wrong since this is the valid by documentation.

Answer (score 0):

add datatype:json in ajax
then
`response.db_password`

else, try parsing it to json.
`let RESULT  = JSON.parse(response) console.log(RESULT.db_password)`

Comment: i cant do it in ajax just via php because it api response

Comment: possible 2 solutions you can try : `$result = $db->body()->toArray();` or `$result = json_encode($db->body()); return $result->db_password;`